# What is the flashback in episode 14 of Ranma referring to?

Tags: ranma

There's a flashback that starts at 15:45 on episode 14 of season 1. I've been watching *Ranma* over the past few days, and I don't think this scene was in a previous episode.

As I recall, the information in the flashback came out as part of a comedy routine. Anime back in those days often had continuity errors like that.

Is this flashback referring to a deleted/modified scene, or is something else going on?

Comment: maybe add some info what is the flashback about? I read the manga but never finished the anime

Answer (score 1):

I think you may instead be referencing episode 15, as this episode introduces Shampoo and has a flashback to the Martial Arts Figure Skating battle, which was originally planned to be air before this episode.

Two episodes were cut from the first season, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ranma_%C2%BD_episodes_(season_1)) notes the reason as there being a sensitive feeling of the title and theme of the specifically the first of these episodes (The Abduction of P-Chan), due to many kidnappings happening in Japan during that time.

These episodes were later inserted into season 2, which is where the clips come from.